# Can't transfer images from a camera connected to a USB 2 port on a PCMCIA adapter

Tags: windows-xp, usb, camera, pcmcia, expansion-cards

I have an old laptop (HP OmniBook vt6200, Windows XP professional, SP2) that only has USB 1 ports. Transferring pictures from a digital camera is too slow, so I thought of trying one of those PC cards carrying USB 2 ports (D-Link Dub C2 in my case).

Connecting the camera to one of the ports on the PC card, Picasa seems to freeze trying to read the camera contents, until I either disconnect the camera or the PC card.

What's wrong?

Comment: i had the same troubles a while back with an older laptop. tried 2 different PCMCIA > USB 2.0 adapters and both were dodgy at the best of times (reading? maybe - writing? in your dreams). i ended up buying a PCMCIA flash memory card reader and all was well.

Comment: Fair enough, but I hoped to use the same card for an external CD burner. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your card adapter driver